# JSON Post request error

Tags: objective-c, json, ios4

I am trying to send user details from registration page in a dictionary using JSON but it shows error "Request without data". How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
NSString *jsonString = [dicRegister JSONRepresentation];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData data];
jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData: %@", string1);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xyz.com/phpFile/methodName/"]];
NSMutableData *requestData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnData: %@", returnString);
```

Comment: Where does this show the error? Are you checking any breakpoints?

Comment: What the return string or what the output string?

Comment: @all: it shows that request is without data..and returnString shows the error message that webService guy has set when there is no data available with the request.

Comment: tell me about the exact response

Comment: @dark: this is the response {"status":"error","msg":"Request without data."} from web service

Comment: This code looks ok .You need to check from server side.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is not with the server it is possible you could be sending an incorrect length to the web service. Since you are using `[jsonString UTF8String]` you should also use `[jsonString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. The documentation says that length returns the count of unicode characters.

Example:

```
NSString *sample = @"El Niño";
NSLog(@"length: %d utf8length: %d",[sample length], [sample lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

produces the output

```
length: 7 utf8length: 8
```

The reason is ñ requires 2 UTF8 characters to represent it.

Comment: Oh wow... I really hit a wall with this. Your insight got me over the hump for the project I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

Code here is okay...there was an error on server side php method....Any way thanx all for your help. :)